# What is wrong in this implementation of Caesar Cipher?

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

I am trying to implement the Caesar cipher but I'm not getting the expected output. What's wrong with the code?

```
Key: 3
Input: Hello
Output I'm getting: KNUUX    
Expected Output: KHOOR
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if(argc!=2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    int k, i;
    k = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("Enter the String to Encrypt: ");
    string s=GetString();
    for(i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if('A'>=s[i]<='Z')
        {
            s[i]=((s[i] - 'A' + k)%26) +'A';
        }
        else if('a'>=s[i]<='z')
        {
            s[i]=((s[i] - 'a' + k)%26) +'a';
        }
    }
    printf("The Encrypted Text is %s\n",s);        
}
```

Comment: Use `isupper()` and `islower()`

Comment: Some advice since you're a beginner, (1) code that compiles is always helpful, (2) typedef'ing or `#define`-ing `char *` as `string` is ***not*** helpful; *ever*.

Comment: @WhozCraig The typedef is part of Harvard-online's CS50 header file. It's just to skirt the issue for the first two or three weeks of the course. For this limited purpose, it is actually quite helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
if('A'>=s[i]<='Z')
```

Is certainly not doing what you seem to be expecting.

You probably want:

```
if ( (s[i] >= 'A') && (s[i] <= 'Z') )
```

Comment: Methinks the comparison is backward on the first expression.

Comment: @WhozCraig ...and that's what I get for copy/pasting from nonsensical code. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, and +1 btw.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0; s[i]; ++i)
    if(isalpha(s[i]))
        s[i]=(toupper(s[i]) - 'A' + k)%26 +'A';
```